# FileUpload in React Native WebView Does Not Work

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement my website into mobile App since it is already mobile optimized. I would like to create an easiness for my users for accessing my website through app both Android and iOS. So I decided to go with react native. Everything run smoothly since almost every function works great.

However, when I try to upload a file on my website as user. I cannot achieve it. I have tried both PlUpload and DropZone. Nothing can works. I click the upload button but it won't go to the phone gallery. I really appreciate any helps. Thank you.